# how to export BPMN 2.0 xml format in bpmn.js

Tags: javascript, bpmn, bpmn.io

in bpmn.js I can import a file contain xml of BPMN 2.0 fromat like this :

```
var BpmnViewer = require('bpmn-js');

var xml; // my BPMN 2.0 xml
var viewer = new BpmnViewer({ container: 'body' });

viewer.importXML(xml, function(err) {

  if (err) {
    console.log('error rendering', err);
  } else {
    console.log('rendered');
  }
});
```

but I dont know how to export with xml format from bpmn project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

answer by **a.sh** from http://forum.bpmn.io

First Of All You should Use "modeler" insteaadiof "viewer".
After that Use blow code

```
    modeler.saveXML({ format: true }, function (err, xml) {
        //here xml is the bpmn format 
    });
```